# Why does \L italicise differently compared to an ordinary L?

Tags: math-operators, italic

The following LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ \L, \operatorname{\L}, \mathrm{\L}
\]
\textit{
\[ \L, \operatorname{\L}, \mathrm{\L}
\]
\[ L, \operatorname{L}, \mathrm{L}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Barred L]

Why does `\L` italicise in `\operatorname` and `\mathrm` environments and how can I prevent it?

Comment: were there any errors in your log?  i don't believe `\L` is recognized in math, so the surrounding `\textit` rules.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed. The error says `\L` is invalid in math mode. Surrounding them with `\mathord{\text{...}}` eliminates these errors but the outputs are identical.

Comment: try `\textrm` then. or `\text{\upshape ...}`.  `\text` all by itself simply follows the style of the current environment, which (as already seen) is `\textit`.  (it's set up this way so that "explanatory text" in a math display in a theorem follows the theorem text style.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed, `\textrm` does not work but `\upshape` does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compiling your example yields six warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \L invalid in math mode
```

What happens is that LaTeX recovers in the only way it knows, that is, switching to the text font which was current when the math formula started. If this is under the scope of `\itshape` (in your case via `\textit`), the Ł will appear in italics.

If you need the slashed L as a math operator, you have to do it more carefully:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lslash}{\text{\normalfont\L}}
```

Here we're under the assumption that the font used by operator names is the same as the main text font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Lslash}{\text{\normalfont\L}}

\begin{document}

$\Lslash$ \textit{$\Lslash$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complex version respecting `\boldmath` and compatible with `\bm` (but operators must be treated specially with it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boldmathTF}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\math@version}{bold}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lslash}{%
  \text{\normalfont\boldmathTF{\bfseries}{}\L}%
}

\begin{document}

$\sin x$ $\Lslash x$

$\bm{\mathop{\sin}}x$ $\bm{\mathop{\Lslash}}x$

\boldmath
$\sin x$ $\Lslash x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any pro of using `\text{\textnormal` rather than `\textnormal{`?

Comment: @Manuel They're essentially equivalent; I was thinking to the possibility of making this compatible with `\boldmath`.